# Get world position of objects in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, object, position, maya

I have an array of objects in Maya, each one has attributes, from which I want to extract their world position. I have created an array :

```
nodesGetPos []
```

And this is the way that I am using to return all of the values:

```
for nGP in nodesGetPos:
        posNew = getAttr(nGP + ".translateX")
        print (posNew)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Maya Attribute does not exist (or is not unique):: u'nPR.translateX' #
```

Comment: Please share the code, what exactly are you trying?

Comment: Did you create your nodeGetPos in python like `nodeGetPos = 0`(note the typo in your question) ? Because if so, what did you do to fill it? As it is, your given lines of code will result in the array to be empty. Therefore it won't yield any results. Not sure if that can produce said error.

Comment: Hi, I have filled my array with objects, and that does work, if I try the ls() command I get the expected result, but I can not create an array with the position of these objects.

Comment: When it gives you that error with the object name, does that object *actually* exist? And if it does, can you confirm that the name is not being used on multiple objects? You can check by passing the name in `cmds.ls()`. If you get more than one result then that means more than one object is sharing the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two command that can help you

```
pos = cmds.xform('pSphere1.vtx[*]', q=1, t=True, ws=True)
```

if you uhave frozen your object, you can get the pivot :

```
pos = cmds.xform('pSphere1.vtx[*]', q=1, rp=True, ws=True)
```